# Nuclear Space problem

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

I need to show that if X is compact,then C(X) is nuclear.Also is the condition X is metrisable 
necessary. I am at present attending a conference "Recent Aadvances in Operator Theory". This
problem was given by Adam Skalski,Warshaw in the conference

Comment: Dear Koushik, What do you mean by $C(X)$? Regards,

Comment: For $X$ compact and Hausdorff, $C(X)^{**}$ is *-isomorphic to some algebra of the form $L_\infty(\mu)$, which as a Banach space, is 1-complemented in any superspace. In particular, it is 1-complemented in the algebra $\mathscr{B}(L_2(\mu))$ (it is identified with the subalgebra of multiplication operators by elements from $L_\infty(\mu)$), hence it is an injective von Neumann algebra. This implies that $C(X)$ is nuclear. 

Comment: The only nuclear Banach spaces are the finite-dimensional ones.  So I repeat the question: what is $C(X)$? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space 

Comment: He is talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_C*-algebra

Comment: yes I mean Nuclear C* algebra. C(X) means the C* algebra of continuous functions from X to C with the std. involution given by its conjugate

Comment: @Koushnik, these facts are probably due to Dixmier; they employ the Radon-Nikodym theorem in a very clever way. A good source of knowledge about $C(K)^{**}$ is the paper of H. G. Dales, A. T.-M. Lau and D. Strauss, Second duals of measure algebras, Dissertationes Math. 481 (2012). Of course, there are more C*-algebraic ways to prove nuclearity of $C(X)$, though this one is my favourite.

Comment: What do you mean you "need to show"? I am sure Adam would be happy to explain it to you, or to advise you where you can look up this result.

Comment: Tomek: using injectivity of the bidual to get nuclearity seems either OTT or else "cheating" by redefining the problem...

Comment: Dear Koushik - seems odd to be communicating this way, since I'm also at the conference - but the proof can be gleaned using the CPA definition of nuclearity. Use the fact that C(X) has a partition of unity (look at Adam's notes to get an idea exactly how). If you want to find me I'm wearing a purple t-shirt with a man riding a dinosaur saying "To the disco!" :)

Comment: just to be sure, is $C(X)\otimes A = C(X,A)$ for any C* algebra $A$ (and any C* tensor product)? 

Comment: What is C(X,A)? as far as I know C(X)⊗C(Y)=C(X*Y)

Comment: Dear Koushik, $C(X,A)$ is the $C^*$ algebra of continuous functions on $X$ with values in $A$. Shouldn't your formula be $C(X)\otimes C(Y)=C(X\times Y)$?

Maybe it's time to close this thread, it is a homework problem. And if Ollie's hint and Adam's notes are not sufficient to solve it, then we'll gladly explain the solution to you in person ;-) 

Comment: I have talked with Ollie and solved it.

Comment: @Ollie: Where is the disco? ;-)

Comment: @yemon choi, at ISI,Bangalore!!!!!

Comment: Burn down the disco / Hang the blessed DJ / Because the music that they constantly play / Says nothing to me about my life

Comment: I'd also vote to close Koushik's question (but not the one posed by Yemon, of course!).